# SQL statement to return overlap from two Select Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table on SQL server and two Select statements with different WHERE criteria

What I want are the results that match both Select Statements, not just one.

I've tried nested SELECT statements but I'm not having much luck.

My table looks like the follow

```
ID    Name    Field2    Field3

1     John     100       NULL
2     Dave     150       NULL
3     Tim      NULL      150
4     Dave     NULL      150
```

And my SELECT statements are as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Field2 = 150
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Field3 = 150
```

But I want to return just 'Dave' because only he appears in the results for both SELECT statements.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select?  Recrods 2 and 4?  Or just one of the records?  Or just the name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`INTERSECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Field2 = 150
INTERSECT
SELECT Name FROM table WHERE Field3 = 150
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
WHERE (Field2 = 150) 
  and exists (select *
              from table1 t2
              where Field3 = 150
               and t1.name = t2.name);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcdb0/6)

Answer (score 0):

or just `inner join`:

```
select name from (
(SELECT name FROM table WHERE Field2 = 150) f2 inner join
(SELECT name FROM table WHERE Field3 = 150) f3 on 
f2.name = f3.name
```